# Can SQL Server 2012 Express coexist with SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

If I install SQL Server 2012 Express (on Windows 7) where I already have SQL Server 2008 Express, will they coexist? And will I be able to use SSMS 2016 connect to one or the other?

Also, since SQL Server 2008 Express is installed in `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLServer\MSSQL\`, where would the SQL Server 2012 Express go?

To the same folder or a different one?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to.  Install just the one 2012 edition.  Then use "backward compatibility mode" one database can be run using the 2012 engine while the other database can be run using the 2008 engine (that comes with the 2012 install).  When you do select @@version you will get one version from one database and another from the other all on the same single server.
(and don't use the express version!!!!  it is useless)

Comment: M T Head.  Thank you.  Helpful suggestion.  Although at this point I can't afford the standard edition. So Express will do.

Comment: **WARNING:** once you've "upgraded" a `.mdf` database file to the **newer** version (SQL Server 2012 Express), you can **NEVER** go back again - you cannot backup & restore, or detach & attach a 2012 `.mdf` back to a SQL Server 2008 instance anymore. The "backward compatibility mode" does not help here, either....

Comment: @marc_s  Yes, I realize that the database cannot be downgraded.  I also found, since my last post, that SQL Server 2014 Express also works on Windows 7.  So this is what I will download and install.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see where you can't use backward compatibility mode.  When you take your 2008 database and put it on 2012.  It comes over as 2008 backward compatibility mode.  Yes you can't put it back on a 2008 server.  But why would you want to.  If you are running 2012 on the box anyway why run two different versions?

Comment: Also if it is a matter of costs.  Express is horribly restricted on its functionality.  If you don't absolutely have to use a MS Sql database I would suggest going to Postgres which is free and does not have the restrictions they put on you with the express version.

Answer (score 1):

> If I install SQL Server 2012 Express (on Windows 7) where I already
>   have SQL Server 2008 Express, will they coexist? And will I be able to
>   use SSMS 2016 connect to one or the other?

Yes they will. I have 4 instances: 2005, 2008R2, 2012 and 2014 installed on the same pc. And yes, you'll be able to connect to all of them using SSMS 2016

> Also, since SQL Server 2008 Express is installed in c:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLServer\MSSQL\, where would the
>   SQL Server 2012 Express go?

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.\MSSQL\

Comment: Thank you for your input.   Unfortunately, after I installed SQL Server 2014 Express, the SSMS 2016 stopped working at all.  When I click on the shortcut for SSMS 2016 I just hear a click but nothing opens and no error message.

Comment: Check the link the shortcut is pointing to, it can be changed. Try to locate SSMS2016 and launch it without using shortcut

Comment: The same - negative - result when I try to launch SSMS2016 from the Programs menu.   I may have to uninstall it and install again.

Comment: Programs menu also contains only shortcuts, but did you try to locate the .exe file and launch it?

Comment: I did.  I do find this file (ssms.exe) in the SQL Server Management Studio folder but the same results when I try to launch it.
The odd thing is that the SSMS is in the Program Files (x86). I thought it should be in the Program Files.  But in any event, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SSMS is typically backward compatible. SQL Server 2017 is different as far as I know. See this for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016

Follow this tutorial if you have any trouble:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/03/14/sql-server-installing-management-studio-sql-server-2016-step-step/

Comment: From what I read online the SQL Server 2016 will not install on Windows 7.  This is why I am considering installing SQL Server 2012 Express.   Thank you.